# Reload a div only if there is new data

Tags: php, ajax

If I create a script like this, then it will reload the div every 2.5 seconds. I want a script that only displays if there is new data, if there is no new data it does not have to reload...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dispMsg() {
        $("#displayMessage").load('load.php');
        var newscrollHeight = $("#displayMessage").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $("#displayMessage").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');
    }
    setInterval (dispMsg, 2500);
});
</script>

<div id="displayMessage"></div>
```

and here is the **load.php**:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $result['id'];
    $from = $result['user_01'];
    $to = $result['to_usr'];
    $message = $result['message_01'];
    $date = $result['date_send'];

    echo "<span class='from'> $from </span>" 
      . "<span class='message'> $message </span> <br/>";
}
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated better to make use of mysqli / pdo

Comment: I'd recommend sorting by `date_send` instead of `id`. This gives you a bullet-proof solution of always get them in descending date order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the parameters and call back of  [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$.load(url, {param1:value, param2:value}, function(result){ 
    if(result >5){ 
     //do something
    }
)
```

Example:

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'check'){
    if($_REQUEST['lastId'] < 5 ){
        echo $_REQUEST['lastId']+1;
        die;
    }
}

if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'load'){
    echo 'some conntent!';
    die;
}

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastId = 0;
    function dispMsg() { 
        $.get('tmp.php', {action:'check', lastId: lastId}, function(responce){

            if(responce !== 0){
                alert(responce);
               $('#displayMessage').load('tmp.php', {action:'load'});
            }
        });

    }
    setInterval (dispMsg, 2500);
});
</script>

<div id="displayMessage">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the last message id with each request. If the last message of your query is greater than the id sent, send the response. Otherwise send nothing.

```
function load_messages(){
    var last = $('#messagewindow p:last').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "load.php",
        type: "POST",
    data: {
        last: last
    },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          //insert message
        }
    });
}
```

You can send the id as the id attribute in your HTML. Each message in the chat window is sent as a paragraph with some message id such as `id="133"`.

Comment: How would the client side know the id?

Comment: I just updated my answer. (I removed what I said before, because it actually was for sending user ids within a span tag which goes beyond what you really asked. It's been a while since I looked at this code.)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Pé de Leão's solution, here's something more simple:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass");
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $msg = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (isset($_REQUEST['last']) && $msg['id'] != $_REQUEST['last']) {
        echo "<span id='${msg['id']}' class='from'>${msg['user_01']}</span>";
    }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
function dispMsg() {
    var last = $('#displayMessages span.from').attr('id');
    $.get(baseUrl + '/load.php', { last: last }, function(result) {
         if (result) {
             $('#displayMessages').html(result);
         }
    });
}
```

Note that this replaces everything in `displayMessages`.